# php Limit query pdo with button next

Tags: php, sql, pdo, pagination, limit

whats the wrong in my code .. i try to click next button to display the next record in database .. but when i clicked nothing happen.

this is my function to fetch record

```
public function getBooks()
{
     $limit = 1;
     $start=0;

    //SELECT loginUser.username, Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username="loay";
    $query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=:username LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statment->execute([
        ':username' => $this->username
        //,':start' => $start, ':limit' => $limit
    ]);
    $result = $statment->fetchAll();

   echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Books</th>
    </tr>";
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['nameOfBook'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

}

And this is my code in index.php

```
  $object->getBooks();

  if( isset($_POST['next'])){
    $start +=1;
}
```

and this is my form code

```html
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  Name: <input type="text" name="user" value="<?php echo $user;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  password: <input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php echo $password;?>" >
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
  <br><br>

 
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick="window.location.href='/ooRigester.php'">SignUp</button>
  <br><br>
  <input type='submit' name='next' value='next' method="post"><br>
</form>
```

this code after form

```
<?php
include_once('User.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$username = $_POST["user"];
$password = $_POST["pass"];

$object = new User();
$object->username= $username;
$object->Password=$password;
if( $object->isAuthenticated() ){

  echo "User Verified . <br><br>";
  $object->getBooks();

  if( isset($_POST['next'])){
    $start +=1;
    $object->getBooks($start); 
}

}

else{

  echo "Wrong User Name Or Password . <br>";
}}


?>
```

and this before form

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
<title>Login Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
/*$str = "Hello";
echo password_hash($str,1);*/
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = "";
$passwordErr = "";
$user = "";
$password = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["user"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $user = test_input($_POST["user"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$user)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }
  if (empty($_POST["pass"])) {
    $passwordErr = "Password is required";
  } else {
    $password = test_input($_POST["pass"]);
  }
  
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: You have to pass the new value of `$start` to `getBooks()` for next to work.

Comment: How ... explain please!

Comment: Add a parameter to `public function getBooks($start = 0)` - like that. Remove `$start=0;` from `getBooks() {..here...}`

Comment: What's the value of $_POST['next'] btw ?

Comment: Can you post your form code?

Comment: i edited my code please check my form code

Comment: Can you pastebin the whole index.php code?

Comment: i edited please check it ...

Comment: I have posted an answer btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Index.php` - you're not setting $start value properly. The below code sets `$start` value from `$_POST['start']` which if non-existent `$start` defaults to 0.

And you're also not accepting form submission properly. I modified the code to accept both submit types (next and login) by doing isset() checks on their $_POST variables.

**Use:**

```
<?php
include_once('User.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']) OR isset($_POST['next'])){
    $username = $_POST["user"];
    $password = $_POST["pass"];

    $object = new User();
    $object->username= $username;
    $object->Password=$password;
    if( $object->isAuthenticated() ){

      echo "User Verified . <br><br>";

      $start = 0;
      if(isset($_POST['start'])){
         $start = $_POST['start'];
      }

      $object->getBooks($start);

    }
}
else{
  echo "Wrong User Name Or Password . <br>";
}


?>
```

In your form code, you have to add a hidden input which holds the offset value of the next database record.

**Use this code:**

```
<form method="post" action="">
  Name: <input type="text" name="user" value="<?php echo $user;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  password: <input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php echo $password;?>" >
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
  <br><br>

  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo (intval(isset($_POST['start'])?$_POST['start']:0)+1);?>" name="start"/>
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick="window.location.href='/ooRigester.php'">SignUp</button>
  <br><br>
  <input type='submit' name='next' value='next' method="post"><br>
</form>
```

Your class method `getBooks()` has to have `$start` parameter so it knows which record is next to be shown.

**Try:**

```
public function getBooks($start = 0)
{
     $limit = 1;

    //SELECT loginUser.username, Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username="loay";
    $query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=:username LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statment->execute([
        ':username' => $this->username
        //,':start' => $start, ':limit' => $limit
    ]);
    $result = $statment->fetchAll();

   echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Books</th>
    </tr>";
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['nameOfBook'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: nice Mr. Blue ... but what is about if(isset($_POST['next'])){}
i need this process when i click on next submit

Comment: It's not needed, but I added it anyways. Check the first code block for update.

Comment: It's fine sir. Btw, I just again made an update to the first code block.

Comment: when i click on the next submit it like i reload the page ... when should i put this code . inside 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$username = $_POST["user"];
$password = $_POST["pass"];
????

Comment: thank you Mr. Blue its work but it is  not exactly like i want there some mistake i don't know where he is ... imagine i want to add previous button when i should added and i have   if(isset($_POST['submit']) OR isset($_POST['next'])){}

Comment: and if i click to the next button he just start from second book and end with 4th book

Comment: I'll try to help you sir up to the previous button. After that I have to leave, as I need to do something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170597/discussion-between-mr-blue-and-husam-almasri).

Answer (score 2):

> code in Controller:

```
function getBooks($start = 0)
{
    $limit = 1;

//SELECT loginUser.username, Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username="loay";
    $query = "SELECT Library.nameOfBook FROM loginUser JOIN userBook JOIN Library ON userBook.user_id = loginUser.id AND userBook.book_id = Library.id WHERE loginUser.username=:username LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $statment = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $statment->execute([
        ':username' => $this->username,
//,':start' => $start, ':limit' => $limit
    ]);
    $result = $statment->fetchAll();

    echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
                <th>Books</th>
            </tr>";

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['nameOfBook'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

> code in index.php.

```
 $object->getBooks();

if( isset($_POST['next']))
{
    $start +=1;
    $object->getBooks($start);  
}
```

Comment: its not work .. please check my form code and tell me whats the wrong